# How to have multiple nav tags

Tags: html, css

On the same page I want a main menu which shows the various pages on my site. I also want a second menu which directs\links users to specific areas of the page. I understand you can have multiple  by using aria-label such as <nav aria-label "primary"> and <nav aria-label "secondary"> but how do you show the styling each one in CSS? Do you use #nav aria-label primary { ?

Comment: `aria-label` is an HTML attribute (with a value of `primary` or `secondary` in this case), so you use the CSS attribute selector, explained best in the target question I linked in the banner above.

Comment: In this case you would style the following **HTML**:

 - `<nav aria-label="primary">...</nav>`
 - `<nav aria-label="secondary">...</nav>`

with the following **CSS**:

 - `nav[aria-label="primary"] {...}`
 - `nav[aria-label="secondary"] {...}`

Comment: Thanks for your answers and the link. Just what I wanted.

Comment: As a newbie I am still confused about the CSS. My HTML for the primary menu reads:  <button><a href="index.html">Home</a></button> so what wording do I use in CSS to show the font height and the background color? Is it nav [aria-label='primary'] { font-size="24"px; background-color="green"; } ?